# Preserve URL State When Logging in With angular-oauth2-oidc

Tags: angular

We are using [angular-oauth2-oidc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-oauth2-oidc) to manage authentication in our Angular app. We're using the Code Flow with PKCE. We want the user to be automatically logged in when they visit the app, so our app is started like this:

```
this.oauthService.configure(authModuleObject);
this.oauthService.loadDiscoveryDocumentAndLogin();
```

We landed on this due to [the documentation's recommendation](https://manfredsteyer.github.io/angular-oauth2-oidc/docs/additional-documentation/manually-skipping-login-form.html). That works just fine. The issue is that if the user comes to the app on a child route (https://myapp.com/some/child/route), and are sent to log in, they come back to the home route again and there's no way to get to the originally requested page.

I've tried following [the documentation here](https://manfredsteyer.github.io/angular-oauth2-oidc/docs/additional-documentation/preserving-state-(like-the-requested-url).html) to get it working, but it doesn't seem to work with the `loadDiscoveryDocumentAndLogin` method.

I tried passing the state in to the method on an object:

```
this.oauthService.loadDiscoveryDocumentAndLogin({ state: 'xxx' })
```

But that doesn't do anything. I also added the `onTokenReceived` method on the options object like the documentation shows, but nothing seems to happen. I can't get access to the state, and it's not been preserved.

This would be a really convenient feature to implement for our users, so I'd like to get it working, but so far I can't get it there.

Comment: I've also subscribed to the events stream and filtered for the `token_received` event. The `info` object on the event is `null`. So I can't seem to get the state to persist.

Answer (score 2):

onTokenReceived was also not working for me, but I had luck with the then() function. In my example I put the url into the state, when I initiate the login. After the login, I read the url from the state and can redirect the user to the subpage.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  authenticationChecked = false;

  constructor(
    @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId,
    private oAuthService: OAuthService,
    private router: Router) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)) {
      this.oAuthService.configure(authCodeFlowConfig);
      this.oAuthService.setStorage(sessionStorage);

      this.oAuthService.loadDiscoveryDocumentAndTryLogin().then(() => {
        const url = this.oAuthService.state;

        if (!!url) {
          this.router.navigateByUrl(decodeURIComponent(url)).then()
        }

        this.authenticationChecked = true;
      });
    }
  }
}
```

init code

```
  initLogin() {
    if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)) {
      if (this.isNotLoggedIn()) {
        this.oAuthService.initLoginFlow(this.router.url)
      }
    }
  }
```